# Rails Ruby Logic for Dynamically updating specific Column Based on Param value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logic

I have caller ID functionality working for my app but I am currently stumped on how to dynamically update the correct column based on the value of `params[:call_number_type]`

`params[:call_number_type]` can be `"alt_phone"`, `"cell_phone"`, `"office_phone"`, or `nil` ... nil defaulting to `"alt_phone"` would be ideal.

Each of the above strings corresponds to a column name that I need to update if `params[:call_number_type]` has that value.

```
@contact = Contact.find(params[:contact_id])

if @contact.update(this_needs_to_be_the_right_column_key: params[:call_number])
```

The above update statement would have to be dynamically created based on the value of `params[:call_number_type]`

If some one could help me out that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if @contact.update(call_number_type => params[:call_number])
  ...

private

def call_number_type
  params[:call_number_type].present? ? params[:call_number_type] : :alt_phone
end
```

Comment: Hey Miles Thanks for the answer! I didn't know the strings themselves would work in place of keys